# Elasticsearch failed to create snapshot error

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, snapshot, elk

I am trying to create snapshot but faced strange issue and don't know how to manage it. It worked before without any problems. Maybe somebody knows what to fix it.

```json
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "snapshot_creation_exception",
        "reason": "[aws_repo:snapshot_19429/N04u4RyBRtmDchd3lgZaMw] failed to create snapshot"
      }
    ],
    "type": "snapshot_creation_exception",
    "reason": "[aws_repo:snapshot_19429/N04u4RyBRtmDchd3lgZaMw] failed to create snapshot",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "i_o_exception",
      "reason": "Unmatched second part of surrogate pair (0xDEA1)",
      "suppressed": [
        {
          "type": "illegal_state_exception",
          "reason": "Failed to close the XContentBuilder",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "i_o_exception",
            "reason": "Unclosed object or array found"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

I am using command `curl -XPUT http://elk:9200/_snapshot/aws_repo/snapshot_19429`

Comment: Could you provide de body of the request ?

Comment: There is empty body

Comment: Could you post the response to this query ? `POST /_snapshot/my_repository/_verify`

Comment: Yeah. Response looks good

```{
  "nodes": {
    "pGzEBdgqQK-ZyeP8pBDMsw": {
      "name": "elk_02"
    },
    "RxT1gbGVRq2gQS21h3kn3Q": {
      "name": "elk_03"
    },
    "H5M0kMj-SJixpTb67zKJpA": {
      "name": "elk_01"
    }
  }
}```

Comment: The how about you try a variation of the example ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/create-snapshot-api.html#create-snapshot-api-example with a body, try a snapshot of a small index perhaps

Comment: Ah....thank you! I didn't think about it. I've created snapshot of small index without any problem. I assume I could write a script to check every single index in a such way.